# Reuse same instance of AWS.S3 in multiple requests to my node.js app

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

Is it safe to use the same instance of AWS.S3 in every request? Does it handle stuff like reconnecting? Or do I need to instantiate the s3 client inside my controller action?

In other words, can I safely instantiate the client outside the scope of the controller action:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3(myAwsConfiguration);

async myControllerAction(ctx, next) {
  let s3Object = null;
  try {
    s3Object = await s3.getObject({
      'Bucket': bucket,
      'Key': key,
    }).promise();
  } catch(e) {
    ctx.throw(500, 'cannot fetch from s3');
  }
}
```

or do I have to do it inside:

```
async myControllerAction(ctx, next) {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3(myAwsConfiguration);

  let s3Object = null;
  try {
    s3Object = await s3.getObject({
      'Bucket': bucket,
      'Key': key,
    }).promise();
  } catch(e) {
    ctx.throw(500, 'cannot fetch from s3');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have learned in the meantime:

**Yes, it is perfectly safe to reuse the same instance.** The s3 protocol is stateless and there is no such thing as a maintained connection that could get lost.

Comment: Hi @simon.ro, thank you for sharing your insight. Do you have any references to the documentation? What about the rest of SDK clients to other services?